Attempting to ReadPixels outside of RenderTexture bounds! Reading (1792, -1008, 2560, -576) from (768, 432)
I'm new to Unity and I have been hardstucked for a couple of days trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
My purpose is to take a screenshot of a "minimap" (actually is turretCamera in the code) that is in the top right corner of the screen. It is 768 pixels width and 432 pixels height.
I leave below my script, any help is appreciated:
EDITED:
Now Coords are well written, but still having the same issue.
EDITED2:
Now RoI has been set to (0,0,targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight)
but the result as it is shown in the image is not the one expected. I would like to full-screen what it is shown in the top right corner.

void Start()
{
  // Configurar el modelo y el trabajador
  Model model = ModelLoader.Load(modelAsset);
  worker = WorkerFactory.CreateWorker(WorkerFactory.Type.ComputePrecompiled, model);

  // Configurar la render texture  
  // Changes made due to @derHugo's appointment
  cameraTopLeftCorner = turretCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, turretCamera.nearClipPlane));
  cameraBottomRightCorner = turretCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, turretCamera.nearClipPlane));

  targetTextureWidth = cameraBottomRightCorner.x - cameraTopLeftCorner.x;
  targetTextureHeight = cameraTopLeftCorner.y - cameraBottomRightCorner.y;

  renderTexture = new RenderTexture(Mathf.CeilToInt(targetTextureWidth),   Mathf.CeilToInt(targetTextureHeight), 24);

  tmpRenderTexture = turretCamera.targetTexture;
  turretCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
  // cameraa.targetTexture = null;
}
private void OnGUI()
{
  // ************Screenshot camera************
  Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24,     false);
  
  RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;

  //RoI set due to @derHugo appointment
  Rect RoI = new Rect(0, 0, targetTextureWidth,     targetTextureHeight);

  Debug.Log("ROI");
  Debug.Log(RoI.xMin +", " + RoI.yMin);
  Debug.Log(RoI.xMax + ", " + RoI.yMax);

  texture2D.ReadPixels(RoI, 0, 0);
  texture2D.Apply();
// ************Screenshot camera************
// rest of code...


For starters Unity screen pixel / viewport coordinates are always 0,0 = bottom -left ->Screen.width, Screen.height / 1,1 = top -right

@derHugo First of all thanks for replying. Second, I have made some changes, but I still have the same issue

As an addition, if I set RoI's coords to (0,0) with the same width and height, then full screen is snapshotted, but I just want the "minimap"

Shouldn't you be then creating a final texture only with the desired size in the first place? Currently you always use the cameras corners .. Unity cameras always render in full screen / player window resolution ...

@derHugo But that is not what I'm actually doing setting "renderTexture" dimensions to "turretCamera " viewport dimensions? (turretCamera is where I want to take the snapshot). Those corners are not full screen but the turretCamera's ones.

Ah I see .. but then why even cutting around at all? in that case you would simply want to readpixels on the entire render texture right? In that case your rect should be 0, 0, targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight

@derHugo done it, but as shown in the new edit, the image is not shown in full-screen, I would like to fill all the black space with the image at top right corner. I don't know if I can resize it to fullfill the entire space...

I think your render texture should also just be RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height); .. Unity's camera anyway renders a full screen resolution

@derHugo, finally I solved it, I just removed RenderTexture in Start() and used Texture2D. Then that Texture2D is being updated in OnGUI(). Thank you so much!!
